# Remove and reorder csv with random carriage returns python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, carriage-return

I have a csv document pulled from a database with random carriage returns. My data (very small subset) looks like this:
[Data in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOUyF.png)

I have 4 columns. The names attribute in column 1 *always* start with NA.
As shown in the picture, the second row start with NAalbert, but then the three next column values for this row is outputted in the next line. The same with the third name NAander, the address is correctly placed, but the next two row values are then placed in the next row.

How can I delete the seemingly random carriage returns in my csv, making the data fit the correct columns?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any extra newlines. `NAalberte;;;` is all on one line.

Comment: Looking at the CSV that you had in your earlier version, it doesn't seem like you have stray "carriage returns", but rather your CSV file is just broken. To fix this algorithmically, one could for example pull in the data from the next row whenever there is a missing field. This approach would only work if there are no blanks in the original data however.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your analysis of the problem @sneep. How would you solve this algorithmically?